# 'Dim as dishwater', or 'dim as ditchwater'?

Tags: metaphors, simile

Is the normal expression 'as dim as dishwater' or 'as dim as ditchwater?

When you google this it comes up as 'dull as dishwater/ditchwater'.

There is a difference between being 'dim' and being 'dull'.

The former means lacking in intelligence and sharpness, what Americans might call 'dumb'. The latter means uninteresting.

So which is it - dim as dishwater/ditchwater - dull as dishwater/ditchwater?

Comment: "Dull" can also mean "mentally slow; slow in perception or ability" (see [MW Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dull)). I've never heard the phrase "dim as ..." either dishwater or ditchwater. Some googling of "dull as ..." suggests that "ditchwater" is the older term, but "dishwater" is more widely used now.

Comment: In fact, if you enter "dim as dishwater" in Google, it apparently assumes you meant "dull as dishwater".

Comment: I've also heard both dishwater/ditch-water with dull, but never with dim. _dim as a toc-H lamp_ would be my phrase of choice for _dim_.

Comment: @Frank yeah, I'd expect many idioms involving "dim" to riff on the fact that it's an antonym of "bright".

Comment: It's always ***dull*** - originally as ***ditchwater***, but [***dishwater*** became dominant over 30 years ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dull+as+dishwater%2Cdull+as+ditchwater%2Cdim+as+dishwater%2Cdim+as+ditchwater&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdull%20as%20dishwater%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdull%20as%20ditchwater%3B%2Cc0). And ***dim*** was never in the running (why would *any* water, even metaphorically, be *dim?*).

Comment: As @FumbleFingers ngram appear to show, ditch-water is in a decline, possibly due to the lack of ditches these days and it got me thinking what is the next natural progression? ditch-water->dishwater-> ... _dishwasher_. Sounds similar, involves dirty water and dishwashers are dull, even the noise they make is mind-numbingly repetitive so I had a look around and sure enough http://www.nytimes.com/1998/09/30/arts/opera-review-revelry-onstage-and-off-at-the-met.html (last sentence second paragraph - from 1998)

Comment: @Frank: Toggling between US/UK corpuses in my NGram there shows that ***dishwater*** is far less common in the UK. On the basis of my own experience, and allowing for a certain amount of misclassification by Google Books, I'd go so far as to say it's virtually unknown my side of the pond. I know ***dishwater*** could be defended on semantic grounds (unlike ***dim***), but I still think it's an eggcorn primarily based on oft-repeated mishearings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I could easily lean that way too - dishwater seems more appropriate for describing weak tea or soup - but I can also imagine that a lot of people, particularly those brought up in cities, have never seen a ditch (let alone one full of water) and _dishwater_ is a more obvious analogy/metaphor to them. And, of course, if it's more common in America then it'll be more common in US movies and therefore will become more common in the UK.

Comment: @Frank I'm surprised there are people on the site (other than me), old enough to appreciate 'dim as as Toc-H lamp'. Surprisingly the Toc-H is not an organisation I have heard mentioned much this year, with all the First World War stuff going on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m surprised you think _dim_ is so illogical here. It certainly seems more logical to me than _dull_: ditch water is most absolutely dim (“Of colour: Not bright; dull, faint; dusky or dark; lustreless”, OED _dim_, sense 3), murky, and hard to see through, more than dull (which, if applied to water, to me implies “Slow in motion or action; not brisk; inert, sluggish, inactive; heavy, drowsy”, OED _dull_, sense 3.a). To me, _dim as ditch water_ makes perfect logical sense in describing someone’s stupidity, while _dull as dishwater_ makes sense for describing a great old bore.

Comment: Also, according to the OED, the oldest form of them all seems to be ***digne [=dain] as ditch water***, meaning ‘stinking with pride’, attested from 1394.

Comment: @Janus: I see the *dullness* of ditch/dishwater as a figurative stretch (from literal "unreflective" to "not interesting"). And to me things are usually only described as *dim* if they actually ***emit*** a low level of light (as opposed to not ***reflecting*** much light, in which case they're ***dull***).

Comment: @Fumble For me, that distinction kind of works, but with the difference that I might use _dim_ to describe the thing itself (‘the car was fitted with dim windows’), but _dull_ only to describe the colour or the ability to reflect (‘the windows were a dull grey’). I wouldn’t talk about ‘dull windows’ that way.

Comment: To the down- and closevoters: how is this question General Reference? The comments above show quite clearly that this idiom is in a state of flux, and that all versions are in use. Hardly something anyone can find in a dictionary.

Comment: I never heard "dim" used with that idiom, only "dull as dishwater".  I always thought it was related to hair color because there's a color (natural, you can't buy this) called "dishwater blond".  Anyway, as illogical as "dull as dishwater" sounds or seems, that's the idiom and "dim as dishwater" would likely have people scratching their heads wondering what metaphors your splicing. :-)

Comment: @Janus: You wouldn't find *either* version (*ditchwater* or *dishwater*) in any dictionary if you were looking for ***dim** as xxxx*. If and when that howler in the question title is changed, I'll retract my closevote.